# Script using sed adds an "e" to the output files

Tags: scripts

I have a script that adds a new user and creates a virtual host for the users domain name. The script works great with one exception... in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ all of my virtual host files have two copies, one with an e and one without.

I believe my issue lies when I use the SED command. Can I get a second opinion?

Here is the script:

```
# set the working directory
dir=$(pwd)

# request the new domain name
printf "Enter the new domain name, without the www (i.e newdomain.com):\n"
read newdomain

# request the new username
printf "Enter the new username (i.e newusername):\n"
read username

# create the new user
sudo adduser $username

# copy the virtual host to sites-available
sudo cp /templates/domain-vhost /etc/apache2/sites-available/$newdomain

# echo results
echo "Successfully created the virtual host file at: /etc/apache2/sites-available/$newdomain.."

# change the domain name in the virtual host file
sudo sed -ie "s/NEWDOMAINNAME/$newdomain/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/$newdomain

# echo results
echo "Modified the virtual host to reflect the new domain: $newdomain.."

# change the directory path in the virtual host
sudo sed -ie "s/NEWUSERNAME/$username/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/$newdomain

# echo results
echo "Successfully modified the new virtual host file.."

# enable the site with apache
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo a2ensite $newdomain

# echo results
echo "Successfully enabled the $newdomain.."

# change to previous working directory
cd $dir

# reload apache
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

# notify user of action
echo "Finished creating the new domain, $newdomain, and restarted Apache.."
```

Comment: Sorry, after typing that I realized my mistake, when using the SED command I had the -i option to edit the file "inline" without creating the copy. For some reason I added the e command as well, which is supposed to add the script. I changed the -ie to -i and the script works as needed. I cannot answer my own question yet so I added a comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need separate `-i` and `-e` arguments to sed. `-ie` is telling sed to create a backup file with an 'e' appended.

[image: manual entry for <code>-i</code>]

To fix, just replace the sed invocation above to:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s/NEWUSERNAME/$username/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/$newdomain
```

Comment: Although you've got a comment with this, I've adding the details as an answer for completeness.

Comment: When I first read this answer I understood what it was saying but didn't immediately grasp why the e was being taken as the suffix. I then checked the manual page and realized the i takes an optional argument. It makes this answer obvious in retrospect but it took me a second to understand the why (hence the image add).